# Consultar un dato CLOB de manera completa en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy guardando en la base de datos, en varias tablas, imágenes en `BASE64`.

Las imágenes que guardo lo realizo en un tipo de dato que se llama `TEXT`, probé hace un `insert` de una cadena de `string` de mas de 200000 caracteres, no me arrojo ningún error, entonces doy a suponer que se encuentra almacenado la totalidad de la cadena `string` que representa cierta imagen en `BASE64`.

Cuando consulto con un simple `select * from table` me trae un dato llamado `[CLOB]` por lo que investigue se llama `Character large object` necesito poder extraer esa información de manera completa ya necesito poder mostrar la imagen correctamente, la única forma que pude encontrar de visualizar esa cadena de caracteres es con la siguiente consulta en un cliente SQL

```sql
SELECT CAST(img_64 AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS ClobColumnName 
FROM table
```

Acá tengo otro problema, la base de datos no permite tener cadenas de caracteres mayor a 8000 con el tipo de dato VARCHAR, se ve que tampoco me permite consultarlos, si utilizo `VARCHAR(8001)` dentro de la consulta ya me arroja un error de limite de caracteres.

Si utilizo PHP (7.3) no necesito hacer la consulta anterior con un `select * from table` me trae la cadena pero recordata no entera.

Que otra forma tengo de poder extraer la cadena de caracteres?

Muchas gracias

Comment: @Alfabravo CLOB no es binario, BLOB sí; en los LOBs normalmente  se almacenan referencias al contenido real.

Comment: Hay un ejemplo en la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.lobs.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si son imagenes, lo mejor es almacenarlas en columnas `varbinary(max)`. Usar `text` es obsoleto (e incorrecto, porque se usaba `image` antes de la versión 2005). Usar cadenas de caracteres puede alterar los datos, en especial si son cadenas con un límite de ocho mil bytes.

Por otro lado, las consultas no cortan el valor guardado, lo que lo corta es el cliente que se usa para desplegar la información. Esto es por cuestiones de memoria, ya que puede ser muy pesado mostrar grandes cantidades de información en pantalla.

Al extraer la información, se tiene que albergar en una variable u objeto para poder manipularlo y convertir esos bytes de nuevo en imagen.

Comment: Si los archivos son <≈ 2GB. Los LOBs pueden almacenar mas.

Comment: Aunque si estás almacenando archivos de más de 2GB en la base de datos, el diseño está mal.

Comment: ¿Entonces para qué existen los LOBs? ¿Acaso los ingenieros de DEC se esforzaron para fomentar malos diseños, una mala práctica que posteriormente implementaron Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc. etc. etc.? Sin estigmatizarlos, hay casos de uso legítimos para LOBs.

Comment: Los hay, claro que sí. Pero si tu base de datos va a tener el 90% de su espacio consumido por LOBs, lo que necesitas es un gestor de archivos para los mismos y dejar la base de datos para datos. Así facilitas la administración de ambos. No solo debemos pensar en el código, también en como se va a administrar el sistema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas, al final pude hablar con la entidad que administra el servidor y me habilitaron un gestor de archivos.